# Downtime ignoring schedule

Tags: screen-time

I've setup screen-time for my daughter's MacBook and want downtime to block apps between 10pm and 6am. But when I set downtime to "on" and scheduled to "on", all apps are blocked on her MacBook no matter what time it is. Inverting the schedule, setting just 4:55am to 5:00am, etc. No matter what, all apps are blocked. Turning downtime off and back on, she gets a notification that she has five minutes until downtime, no matter what the schedule says.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to untick downtime "on". It may be confusing, but setting downtime on overrides the scheduled downtime. You will see once your scheduled downtime kicks in, the upper normal downtime indicator will show "on" automatically.

Comment: This is seriously non-intuitive! Thanks though... I was running into this same issue.